# Jisti Videobridge using Node js

Tags: webrtc, jitsi, jitsi-meet

Currenrtly we are using Kurento for 1-many & many-many video calls using Node Js ( [Kurento Tutorial](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/node/tutorial-one2one.html) ).

We are now planning to move to Jitsi-videobridge.
Is there any example / tutorial of how to use Jitsi-videobridge with NodeJs?

All I could find is Jitsi-meet with nginx/apache without any explanation.

Any documentation / tutorial for Jitsi-Videobridge with Node will be great

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately we don't have much documentation in that area. Here is the REST API you'd need to implement: https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-videobridge/blob/master/doc/rest.md Then you need to convert COLIBRI to SDP and do the usual WebRTC dance. It won't be a walk in the park, I'm afraid.

Comment: @sa I too would be interested in more documentation or tutorials on how to use just the Jitsi-videobridge portion. Documentation is pretty much non-existant. I like the idea of using the videobridge as a SFU only.